# How to run single powershell command on ansible?

Tags: powershell, ansible

Here is the powershell command on my playbook:

```
- name: "Execute Powershell from Ansible"
  ignore_errors: yes
  ansible.windows.win_shell: (Get-Acl -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn") | Format-list
```

Here is error from ansible:

```
{
"ansible_loop_var": "item",
"_ansible_no_log": false,
"item": "(Get-Acl -Path \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\Binn\") | Format-list",
"changed": false,
"msg": "Get-AnsibleParam: Missing required argument: _raw_params",
"_ansible_item_label": "(Get-Acl -Path \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\Binn\") | Format-list" 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
Here is the yaml:

```
- name: Execute Powershell from Ansible
  win_shell: |
    Get-Acl -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn" | Format-list
    Get-Acl -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\COM" | Format-list
    Get-Acl -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Shared" | Format-list
    Get-Acl -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Shared\ErrorDumps" | Format-list
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is

> Missing required argument: _raw_params

Escape the quotes the other way, like this:

```yaml
- name: Execute Powershell from Ansible
  ansible.windows.win_shell: |
    Get-Acl -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn" | Format-list
```

And also, do not use `ignore_errors: yes` as the first module to use.